# Interpolate a curve on itself using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have the following curve as two arrays, of x and y positions.

[image: curve]

Imagine if you were to draw vertical lines going through each point, and add points on the curve wherever these lines intersect the curve. This is what I want.

I tried using `np.interp(x, x, y)`, but I ended up with the following mess:

[image: mess]

How can I do this? Is it possible with `np.interp`?

This might be something that should be asked in a different question, but I would also like there to be points added where the curve crosses over itself.

Comment: You will need to add another column to describe the relationship of x and y with another dimension. For example, if each point on the graph can be referenced to a time, then you could try either a 3 term non linear least squared method or radial basis function. These functions are both available in SciPy. If you can post your code which produced the chart,  then perhaps I can show you how to use those methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) the array of X values should be sorted (or periodic), otherwise "the result is nonsense". You can try to split your curve into sections, and then interpolate each part on the others. You can find the correct splitting places by looking at where `np.diff(x)` changes sign.